# Time data: Wide to Long

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am not sure if I am even using the term wide/long correctly, but I am trying to reformat shift data in a way that I can see how much labor is being used in hourly increments.

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
library(data.table)
sample_DT <- data.table(
  store = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  date = ymd(c("2019-03-24", "2019-03-24", "2019-03-24", "2019-03-24", "2019-03-24", "2019-03-24")),
  start_hr = c(23,0,2,7,4,2),
  duration_hr = c(8,4,4,12,6,10)
  )
```

which looks like:

```
     store     date    start_hr duration_hr
   <char>     <Date>    <num>       <num>
1:      A 2019-03-24       23           8
2:      A 2019-03-24        0           4
3:      A 2019-03-24        2           4
4:      A 2019-03-24        7          12
5:      B 2019-03-24        4           6
6:      B 2019-03-24        2          10
```

I am trying to see how much labor stores use during each hourly interval (0-1, 1-2, 2-3, 3-4,...) on each date. So the data should look something like:

```
store    date    time_hr usage
A   2019-03-24    0       1
A   2019-03-24    1       1
A   2019-03-24    2       2
A   2019-03-24    3       2
A   2019-03-24    4       1
A   2019-03-24    5       1 
B   ...
B   ...
```

In the above, `time_hr` represents the time interval (e.g., `time_hr = 0` means the interval from midnight to 1 AM). Please note that sometimes the shifts can run multiple days (e.g. starts at 23:00 and has a duration of 8 hours).

Thanks!

Comment: First this has nothing with pivoting the data. Your title is misleading. Second, your information is incomplete. You just talked about time_hr. What aboute usage? How do you calculate that?

Comment: Sorry if this question was ambiguous, which is why I wrote that I wasn’t sure if it was the correct terminology. I’ve described what the time_hr variable in my text.

Comment: you did describe time_hr, but didnot describe usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done a few ways, here's a way using pivoted data so that each shift start is turned into a `+1` and each shift end into a `-1`.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(lubridate)
sample_df %>%
  transmute(store, 
            start_hr = ymd_h(paste(date, start_hr)),
            end_hr = start_hr + dhours(duration_hr)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-store, 
               names_to = "change",
               values_to = "timestamp") %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(change == "start_hr", 1, -1)) %>%
  count(store, timestamp, wt = change, name = "change") %>%  # total change/hr
  arrange(store, timestamp) %>%
  complete(store, 
           timestamp = seq.POSIXt(min(timestamp), max(timestamp), 
                                  by = "hour"), 
           fill = list(change = 0)) %>%
  mutate(usage = cumsum(change))
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 64 × 4
   store timestamp           change usage
   <chr> <dttm>               <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A     2019-03-24 00:00:00      1     1
 2 A     2019-03-24 01:00:00      0     1
 3 A     2019-03-24 02:00:00      1     2
 4 A     2019-03-24 03:00:00      0     2
 5 A     2019-03-24 04:00:00     -1     1
 6 A     2019-03-24 05:00:00      0     1
 7 A     2019-03-24 06:00:00     -1     0
 8 A     2019-03-24 07:00:00      1     1
 9 A     2019-03-24 08:00:00      0     1
10 A     2019-03-24 09:00:00      0     1
# … with 54 more rows
```

Comment: This is really wonderful, thank you so much. Could explain what the `change` variable is doing? Thanks!

Comment: It records that each start_hr means the number in usage is increasing by 1 at that point, and that each end_hr is reducing the usage by 1. Then I summarize those by hour, fill in the missing hours, and the usage is the cumulative sum of those changes. You can remove it with `%>% select(-change)`, I just kept it to show a bit of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that uses data.table, and splits out a small function `f` that makes a sequence of hr intervals.. The distinct intervals are then summed by store.

```
f <- function(d,h, dur) seq(ymd_h(paste(d,h)), by="hour",length.out=dur)

sample_DT[,id:=.I] %>% 
  .[, .(hr_interval = f(date,start_hr, duration_hr)), by=.(store, id)] %>% 
  .[, .(usage = .N), .(store, hr_interval)] %>% 
  .[order(store,hr_interval)]
```

Output:

```
    store         hr_interval usage
 1:     A 2019-03-24 00:00:00     1
 2:     A 2019-03-24 01:00:00     1
 3:     A 2019-03-24 02:00:00     2
 4:     A 2019-03-24 03:00:00     2
 5:     A 2019-03-24 04:00:00     1
 6:     A 2019-03-24 05:00:00     1
 7:     A 2019-03-24 07:00:00     1
 8:     A 2019-03-24 08:00:00     1
 9:     A 2019-03-24 09:00:00     1
10:     A 2019-03-24 10:00:00     1
11:     A 2019-03-24 11:00:00     1
12:     A 2019-03-24 12:00:00     1
13:     A 2019-03-24 13:00:00     1
14:     A 2019-03-24 14:00:00     1
15:     A 2019-03-24 15:00:00     1
16:     A 2019-03-24 16:00:00     1
17:     A 2019-03-24 17:00:00     1
18:     A 2019-03-24 18:00:00     1
19:     A 2019-03-24 23:00:00     1
20:     A 2019-03-25 00:00:00     1
21:     A 2019-03-25 01:00:00     1
22:     A 2019-03-25 02:00:00     1
23:     A 2019-03-25 03:00:00     1
24:     A 2019-03-25 04:00:00     1
25:     A 2019-03-25 05:00:00     1
26:     A 2019-03-25 06:00:00     1
27:     B 2019-03-24 02:00:00     1
28:     B 2019-03-24 03:00:00     1
29:     B 2019-03-24 04:00:00     2
30:     B 2019-03-24 05:00:00     2
31:     B 2019-03-24 06:00:00     2
32:     B 2019-03-24 07:00:00     2
33:     B 2019-03-24 08:00:00     2
34:     B 2019-03-24 09:00:00     2
35:     B 2019-03-24 10:00:00     1
36:     B 2019-03-24 11:00:00     1
    store         hr_interval usage
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I would like to mention the `coverage()` function from the `IRanges` package which does all the heavy labour. It works on intervals which allows for a compact RLE (run length encoded) representation of the result as well as turning this into a grid display as requested by the OP.

The only drawback is that it needs *integer* intervals. So, we have to coerce the date-time intervals to integer intervals to and fro.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)
if (!"IRanges" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) {
  install.packages("IRanges", 
                   repos = "https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.15/bioc")
}
library(IRanges)

origin <- min(d$date)
usage <- d[, IRanges(start = as.integer(date - origin) * 24L + start_hr, 
                     width = duration_hr, 
                     names = store)] %>% 
  split(names(.)) %>% 
  coverage() 

usage
```

> ```
> RleList of length 2
> $A
> integer-Rle of length 30 with 7 runs
>   Lengths:  1  2  2  1 12  4  8
>   Values :  1  2  1  0  1  0  1
>
> $B
> integer-Rle of length 11 with 4 runs
>   Lengths: 1 2 6 2
>   Values : 0 1 2 1
> ```

For each shop, this is a run length encoded representation of the usage (or coverage). For shop `A`, e.g., there is a usage of 1 in the first hour, during the next 2 hours there is a usage of 2 and so forth.

This can be coerced into a more comprehensible representation of usage intervals:

```
lapply(usage, function(x) data.table(
  start_dt = origin + hours(start(x) - 1L),
  duration_hr = width(x),
  usage = runValue(x))) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "shop")
```

> ```
>       shop            start_dt duration_hr usage
>  1:      A 2019-03-24 00:00:00           1     1
>  2:      A 2019-03-24 01:00:00           2     2
>  3:      A 2019-03-24 03:00:00           2     1
>  4:      A 2019-03-24 05:00:00           1     0
>  5:      A 2019-03-24 06:00:00          12     1
>  6:      A 2019-03-24 18:00:00           4     0
>  7:      A 2019-03-24 22:00:00           8     1
>  8:      B 2019-03-24 00:00:00           1     0
>  9:      B 2019-03-24 01:00:00           2     1
> 10:      B 2019-03-24 03:00:00           6     2
> 11:      B 2019-03-24 09:00:00           2     1
> ```

Alternatively, the usage can be displayed as a sequence of hourly intervals as requested by the OP:

```
lapply(usage, function(x) data.table(
  usage = decode(x))[, timestamp := origin + hours(seq_along(usage) - 1L)]) %>% 
  rbindlist(idcol = "shop")
```

> ```
>       shop usage           timestamp
>  1:      A     1 2019-03-24 00:00:00
>  2:      A     2 2019-03-24 01:00:00
>  3:      A     2 2019-03-24 02:00:00
>  4:      A     1 2019-03-24 03:00:00
>  5:      A     1 2019-03-24 04:00:00
>  6:      A     0 2019-03-24 05:00:00
>  7:      A     1 2019-03-24 06:00:00
>  8:      A     1 2019-03-24 07:00:00
>  9:      A     1 2019-03-24 08:00:00
> 10:      A     1 2019-03-24 09:00:00
> 11:      A     1 2019-03-24 10:00:00
> 12:      A     1 2019-03-24 11:00:00
> 13:      A     1 2019-03-24 12:00:00
> 14:      A     1 2019-03-24 13:00:00
> 15:      A     1 2019-03-24 14:00:00
> 16:      A     1 2019-03-24 15:00:00
> 17:      A     1 2019-03-24 16:00:00
> 18:      A     1 2019-03-24 17:00:00
> 19:      A     0 2019-03-24 18:00:00
> 20:      A     0 2019-03-24 19:00:00
> 21:      A     0 2019-03-24 20:00:00
> 22:      A     0 2019-03-24 21:00:00
> 23:      A     1 2019-03-24 22:00:00
> 24:      A     1 2019-03-24 23:00:00
> 25:      A     1 2019-03-25 00:00:00
> 26:      A     1 2019-03-25 01:00:00
> 27:      A     1 2019-03-25 02:00:00
> 28:      A     1 2019-03-25 03:00:00
> 29:      A     1 2019-03-25 04:00:00
> 30:      A     1 2019-03-25 05:00:00
> 31:      B     0 2019-03-24 00:00:00
> 32:      B     1 2019-03-24 01:00:00
> 33:      B     1 2019-03-24 02:00:00
> 34:      B     2 2019-03-24 03:00:00
> 35:      B     2 2019-03-24 04:00:00
> 36:      B     2 2019-03-24 05:00:00
> 37:      B     2 2019-03-24 06:00:00
> 38:      B     2 2019-03-24 07:00:00
> 39:      B     2 2019-03-24 08:00:00
> 40:      B     1 2019-03-24 09:00:00
> 41:      B     1 2019-03-24 10:00:00
>       shop usage           timestamp
> ```

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
d <- data.table(
  store = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B"),
  date = ymd(rep("2019-03-24", 6L)),
  start_hr = c(23, 0, 2, 7, 4, 2),
  duration_hr = c(8, 4, 4, 12, 6, 10)
)
```